# How to update local repository using GitLab UI?

Tags: github, gitlab, github-desktop

I was looking to update my local repository using GitLab UI. Is this possible without using the command line or any other client application such as GitHUB desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab UI represents first your *remote* repos, as hosting by the *remote* Git repositories hosting servers.

It can show you the git command to execute in order to clone your Git repository, but you would *still* need to use that URL in a local tool or CLI, like `git clone /url/gitlab/repo`.